# fabric js: objects grouping is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, grouping, fabricjs

I am having problem with grouping multiple objects on canvas. When I select objects using holding down shift key and then if I make a group of those objects, the newly added group has incorrect z-index of it's items. Pleas run the snippet bellow to understand the problem. 
Please select green box first, then select blue and then red while the shift key is pressed. Then clik on Group button to see the problem.

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  isDrawingMode: false,
  preserveObjectStacking: true
});

  

fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = true;
canvas.setWidth(380);
canvas.setHeight(310);
canvas.setBackgroundColor('#F2F2F2');
canvas.renderAll();


var topMost = new fabric.Rect({
     left: 90,
     top: 90,
     width: 50,
     height: 50,
     fill: 'green',
});

var middle = new fabric.Rect({
     left: 70,
     top: 70,
     width: 50,
     height: 50,
     fill: 'blue',
});

var bottom = new fabric.Rect({
     left: 50,
     top: 50,
     width: 50,
     height: 50,
     fill: 'red',
});

canvas.add(bottom);
canvas.add(middle);
canvas.add(topMost);


$(".group").on('click', function () {
    var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();

    activegroup.clone(function (newgroup) {
        canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        objectsInGroup.forEach(function (object) {
        canvas.remove(object);
        });
        canvas.add(newgroup);
    });
});
```

```css
h3{color: blue;}h5{color: red;}canvas{border: 2px solid black;}
button{padding: 8px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>

<h3>Please select green box first, then select blue and then red while the shift key is pressed. Then clik on Group button to see the problem</h3>
<h5>Problem: Grouping multiple objects, selected using shift key down, changes their z-index after grouped</h5>
<button class="group">Group</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric has never automatically preserved object order in groups. I see you were using `preserveObjectStacking = true`, and I think this might have caused your confusion. This property does not affect the actual order of the objects to "preserve" the way they are on the canvas. Instead, it changes the order the objects appear to have while selected, as well as the click-target-finding when clicking on these objects.

Objects in the active selection are added in the order of clicking, and adding with preserveObjectStacking, they get rendered in canvas order. The first 2 objects get ordered in stack order anyway.

In your specific case, you click

1. green -> activeObject
2. blue -> blue is under green so you get activeGroup with blue, green.
3. red -> red gets pushed in active group at end of objects array.

The order that you get when you clone is exactly blue, green, red.

To preserve the order that the objects have on the canvas, you can easily write a sort function and run it against your group's objects before cloning it.

```
var sorter = function (a, b) {
    var idxA = canvas._objects.indexOf(a),
        idxB = canvas._objects.indexOf(b);
    return idxA > idxB ? 1 : 0; 
};

var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
activegroup._objects.sort(sorter);
var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects(); //these are now in the canvas's order
//.....continue with your original code
```